# Separation of SQL Expression

Tags: sql, text-parsing

I have an input:

```
(123)555-234-556,(321)333-324-223
```

I need to separate and assign the first half (until the comma) to variable A and the second half to variable B.
Also I need to be able to form the parts to something like:

```
123-555-234-556
```

Comment: To confirm, is this entire string is stored in one column? It will help to know what database management system you're using. MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL solution:

```
SELECT substring(t,2,3)||'-'||substring(t,6)
FROM unnest(string_to_array('(123)555-234-556,(321)333-324-223',',')) as t
```

Answer (score 0):

alternative PostgreSQL Solution, assuming you want the values in two separate columns:

First having both of them in two columns (I suspect you meant columns).

```
select 
substring(input,0,position(',' in input)) as A, 
substring(input,position(',' in input)+1) as B
from (select '(123)555-234-556,(321)333-324-223'::varchar as input) fakeInput
```

the second part then is

```
substring(A,2,3) || '-' || substring(A,6) as modifiedA
```